# How to skip subsequent exception handling in Visual Studio to quickly exit break mode?

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2022

When I am debugging my Asp Net Core application using Microsoft Visual Studio and some exception occurs,
to exit break mode I have to keep pressing "Continue" button for a minute until exception bubbles to the bottom through all call stack.

Is there a way to easily skip all subsequent exception handlings?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to easily skip all subsequent exception handlings?

Well, if you would like to configure exceptions in visual studio while debugging of course you can do that.

In other word, you can customize your exception defination in visual studio in which exception need to ignore and which need to point at.

**Exception Setting In Visual Studio:**

In the visual studio within **Exception Settings window** you can navigate to (**Debug > Windows > Exception Settings)** in order to check the type of exception you want to skip or point at.

Please have a look at the following picture:

[image]

Output:

[image]

**Note:** At the bottom window, you can check or uncheck which one you want to debug or want to ignore. You can get [more details here in the official document.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/managing-exceptions-with-the-debugger?view=vs-2022)

Comment: In my case I don't want to ignore certain type of exceptions. I am just looking for a way to quickly exit break mode without clicking 'Continue' 100 times if exception handling chain is long.

Comment: Sure, in that case you can customize that so better to check that document what you want to keep and what to skip. Thanks.